# Sudden DTU spikes in Azure SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

Our SQL Azure databases gets sudden spikes on random moments during the week. Once these spikes happen they don't stop anymore. There is nothing happening abnormally at those moments.

If we scale up or scale down our SQL the spikes stop and we have our normal behavior again.

How can we troubleshoot this problem? I have a feeling something is 'stuck' and is suddenly hogging our SQL.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Use [Query Store](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/monitoring-performance-by-using-the-query-store) to identify the culprits. Activate [Query Performance Insight](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-query-performance) on your account and then review the top consuming queries when the DTU spikes occur.

> If we scale up or scale down our SQL the spikes stop and we have our normal behavior again

That looks like something only an Azure ticket can investigate.

Comment: When you scale up or down an Azure database, the scaling will actually break any connections for a second or less.  So, I suspect that act of scaling is disconnecting any job that is hitting your database and perhaps causing the calling app to die (for a time).  So the scaling isn't actually stopping it, but the database disconnection associated with scaling is stopping it.